# BMC Discount on Climbing Walls

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, uk, bmc

What does the [BMC](https://www.thebmc.co.uk) membership discount encompass? Is it just climbing and mountaineering shops or is it other paid for services?

More specifically, would the BMC membership discount apply to the entrance fees of either the Boardroom (Deeside) or Beacon (Caernarfon) climbing centres?

Comment: I climb at the Boardroom, and no they don't offer BMC discounts, currently, I have asked and they have no plans to.

Comment: @Liam What's the Boardroom like? Are there any other decent walls in the area?

Comment: It's good, not the cheapest. The bouldering is ok but the route climbing is excellent. There are 2 walls (that I know of) in Liverpool (http://www.theclimbinghangar.com/ & http://www.awesomewalls.co.uk/climbing-centres/liverpool/liverpool-overview-page). There's also the walls @ [Plas y brenin](http://www.pyb.co.uk/). There's nothing nearer, quite a few limestone crags near by if you can go outdoors.

Comment: @Liam I'm mostly into bouldering, and spend a lot of time in Snowdonia

Comment: The climbing hanger is the place to go for bouldering. It's got easily 4 times the routes as the boardroom. Awesome walls in stoke is good too.BTW, never been to the Beacon so I couldn't advise there.

Comment: pop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp) sometime if you need advice

Comment: @Liam Good idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see a list of the mebership discounts currently at:

https://www.thebmc.co.uk/membership-discounts

It covers a wide variety of things.

TBH, if your looking to join the BMC for a discount it's likely not worth it. Often I get better discounts from memberships to walls, etc.

---

(*hold on a second while I get on this high horse*)

The BMC is really an organisation that promotes climbers rights and interests in the UK, that's why you should join it.

Comment: I'm already a member :D